# How to add delay inside StreamBuilder before switching to new Widget?

Tags: flutter

I have got `StreamBuilder`. I am trying to do progress indicator with it. Like:

```
Loading token DONE
Loading regions DONE
Loading industry DONE
```

After the last item ("Loading industry DONE") and before switching to `HomePage` I would like to add small delay. But I can't understand how to do it. I tried to use `Future.delayed` and `Timer`, but with them switching to HomePage do not happen. Without Delay/Timer switching works, but I need delay before it.

Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:flutter/semantics.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'main.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  SplashScreenState createState() => SplashScreenState();
}

class SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  String tokenLoadingState = '';
  String regionsLoadingState = '';
  String industryLoadingState = '';
  TenderApiProvider apiProv;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    apiProv = Provider.of<TenderApiProvider>(context);
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: apiProv.resultController,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          TenderApiProvider apiProv = Provider.of<TenderApiProvider>(context);

          if (snapshot.data is ApiKeyLoadingState) {
            switch (snapshot.data) {
              case ApiKeyLoadingState.Progress:
                tokenLoadingState = "Loading";
                break;
              case ApiKeyLoadingState.Done:
                tokenLoadingState = "Done";
                break;
              case ApiKeyLoadingState.Error:
                tokenLoadingState = "Error";
                break;
              default:
                return Text("Unknown");
            }
          } else if (snapshot.data is RegionsLoadingState) {
            switch (snapshot.data) {
              case RegionsLoadingState.Progress:
                regionsLoadingState = "Loading";
                break;
              case RegionsLoadingState.Done:
                regionsLoadingState = "Done";
                break;
              case RegionsLoadingState.Error:
                regionsLoadingState = "Error";
                break;
              default:
                return Text("Unknown");
            }
          } else if (snapshot.data is IndustryLoadingState) {
            switch (snapshot.data) {
              case IndustryLoadingState.Progress:
                industryLoadingState = "Loading";
                break;
              case IndustryLoadingState.Done:
                industryLoadingState = "Done";
                break;
              case IndustryLoadingState.Error:
                industryLoadingState = "Error";
                break;
              default:
                return Text("Unknown");
            }

            if (apiProv.apiKeyLoadingState == ApiKeyLoadingState.Done &&
                apiProv.regionsLoadingState == RegionsLoadingState.Done &&
                apiProv.industryLoadingState == IndustryLoadingState.Done) {

              Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000)).then(
                  (_) => HomePage() // I need delay before switching to HomePage
              );

            }
          }

          return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(),
              body: Center(
                  child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Loading token: $tokenLoadingState",
                    textScaleFactor: 2,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Loading regions: $regionsLoadingState",
                    textScaleFactor: 2,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Loading industry: $industryLoadingState",
                    textScaleFactor: 2,
                  ),
                ],
              )));
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move you logic outside of the build method. 
The build method in flutter must not have a delay, else your UI would lag very heavy.

For your usecase, StreamBuilder might not fit. It fits for dynamically displaying content depending of the state of your stream. It tho is not suitable for Routing or Navigation, as this would break the build process of the widget.
That means, you have to manually subscribe to the stream.
Here is an example. I cant test it, because you have many hidden dependencies.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      TenderApiProvider apiProv = Provider.of<TenderApiProvider>(context);
      apiProv.resultController.listen((data) async {
        if (apiProv.apiKeyLoadingState == ApiKeyLoadingState.Done &&
            apiProv.regionsLoadingState == RegionsLoadingState.Done &&
            apiProv.industryLoadingState == IndustryLoadingState.Done) {

          await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));// I need delay before switching to HomePag
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');

        }
      });

    });

  }
```

As I can sense you are fairly new to flutter, please consider taking one of the existing free video courses available on youtube.

Comment: I am getting error, that there is another listener of stream. I suppose it `stream: apiProv.resultController,`

Comment: And second error `The getter 'resultController' was called on null`

Comment: Yes, you will have to change your implementation accordingly. Did you remove the Stream Builder?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import 'dart:async';

Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () => HomePage());
```

Comment: Do not helped( do not switch to HomePage. could you explain is my code ok, or it's have issue with it's logic?

Comment: Is your App loading homepage?

Comment: no, it's load this widget, and do now switch to HomePage

Comment: Try printing all the states and check if all the states are Done. If not then check where it is going wrong.

Comment: They are all done. If I remove Timer or Delay all works. But I need to add delay before switching to show user that all items Done.

Comment: sleep(const Duration(seconds: 1)); //import 'dart:io';